# Logging issues with Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have added Resque to my Rails 3 project. I have created a job which reads/writes some stuff from/to the DB.

The problem is I do not see the SQL query logs such as "Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"" in the terminal anymore. I am also not seeing any Rails.logger messages I have set up.

When I make yet another request (simple refresh) the logger messages and SQL query logs suddenly show up.

Any ideas what could be going on? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Rails won't write out to the log file immediately, it waits for a certain amount of lines to go by before flushing the file. You can tell Rails to always flush the log by adding this to your `development.rb` or `application.rb` file...

```
config.logger.auto_flushing = true
```

Only ever do this in development, and never set this in production as it will just kill your I/O.

You can also do it on demand with...

```
Rails.logger.flush
```

API documentation here...

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BufferedLogger.html#method-i-auto_flushing-3D

Comment: ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger#auto_flushing is deprecated on Rails 3.2 now. Instructions are to either set the sync level on the underlying file handle, or tune your filesystem. The FS cache is now what controls flushing.   
file = File.open(‘foo.log’, ‘w’)
file.sync = true   
ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new file

Comment: formatting is pretty screwed up on that, you can see this better in the docs under the "Deprecations" section - https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/railties/guides/source/3_2_release_notes.textile

Comment: @Jimbo - The problem with that deprecation message is that I have no idea what "set the sync level on the underlying file handle" means.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier - haha, I vaguely remember writing this, so unfortunately I'm not quite sure either (and the link is broken... :/ ). I think I was referring to this (adding semicolons to differentiate between lines) - `file = File.open(‘foo.log’, ‘w’); file.sync = true; ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new file`

Comment: Here is the correct link to the [Ruby on Rails 3.2 Release Notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html) that says: "`ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger#auto_flushing` is deprecated. Either set the sync level on the underlying file handle like this. Or tune your filesystem. The FS cache is now what controls flushing."

Answer (score 2):

We experienced the same issue in one of our projects. Additionally we wanted to log all Resque messages to a separate log file too.

In the blog post [Enable immediate log messages of resque workers](http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/enable-immediate-log-messages-of-resque-workers) a code sample can be found to enable the immediate logging to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Resque won't flush the log in production mode (unless your job is generating more than 1000 lines of log).

You will have to flush for every line of log generated. I would configure only resque with the file lib/tasks/resque.rake :

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  Resque.before_first_fork = Proc.new { Rails.logger.auto_flushing = 1 }
end
```