# Resque worker on Heroku doesn't log without the (deprecated) VERBOSE flag set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, resque

I have Resque set up on Heroku, but in both development and production, I can't figure out how to make Resque log without setting `VVERBOSE=1` or `VERBOSE=1`.

I've tried changing `Resque.logger.level`, logging at a variety of levels, as well as setting `Rails.logger.auto_flushing` (which is no longer available) as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957649/1067145

The article http://jademind.com/blog/posts/enable-immediate-log-messages-of-resque-workers/ is somewhat relevant, but I don't want to log to a file-- just to `STDOUT`.

I'm not sure if the issue is due to `Resque`'s default logger not flushing eagerly enough, or something else.

How can I eagerly log to `STDOUT` within a `Resque` worker, in a Rails 4 environment? Is there any way I can force the default logger to flush?